# get the count of each status based on Id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a master table called `mail_recievers_master` and child table called `mail_recievers`. common_id is the `primary key` in master table and `foreign` key in child table.

I can get the master details by using

```sql
select * 
from mail_recievers_master
```

With this query we will get the all details in master table. This is fine.

As we know that master table is going to have one record per `common_id` and in child table there will be multiple records for `common_id`, as the child table contains the mail receivers.

In child table `mail_recievers` I am going to have status column in that I am going to store weather the mail `sent` or `Invalid` or `bounced` or `Initiated` I am going to store.

When record inserted the status will be `Initiated` when bounced the status will be `bounced` when mail sent the status will be  `sent`. So I might be having only `sent` status records or  `Sent` with `Bounced` or `sent`, `bounced`, `Initiated`.

Here my requirement is I need to get all the details of the master table and based on individual `common_id` I need to get the count of all the statuses.

The `common_id` might have one  or more statuses and I need to get count of all the statuses.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for conditional aggregation, showing all counts per mail in one row.

```
select * 
from mail_recievers_master mrm
left join
(
  select
    common_id,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'sent') as sent,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'invalid') as invalid,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'bounced') as bounced,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'initiated') as initiated
  from mail_recievers
  group by common_id
) mr on mr.common_id = mrm.common_id
order by mrm.common_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am getting the error like `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 7:     count(*) filter (where status = 'Sent') as sent,
                            ^`

Comment: I'm not getting this error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=08b7aa6857f00b64dc5e26c35cd7969d. Please check column names and types. Especially: Is there a column named status in table mail_recievers and is this a text column?

Comment: I don't see any reason then for the error message. As you can see from the dbfiddle link, this should work. Does the following query run? `select common_id from mail_recievers where status = 'sent';`.

Comment: the above query is perfectly worked for me, in the link you are using `PostgreSQL 13.0` but I  am using in my local `9.x ` will it become an issue?

Comment: According to the docs, the filter clause was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.4, which is so old that it is already unsupported. I changed the fiddle to PostgreSQL 9.5 and it is  running fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=08b7aa6857f00b64dc5e26c35cd7969d. You can use that fiddle, too. Replace the `CREATE TABLE` statements with your original ones and see whether you are getting the error then. If so, post the new fiddle link.

Comment: In older versions, you can replace `count(*) filter (where status = 'sent')` by `count(case when status = 'sent' then 1 end)`.

Answer (score 0):

Join the 2 tables using the `common_id` column, and then `group by` the status column to arrive at the count: e.g.

```
select
       det.status
     , count(*) as count_of
from from mail_recievers_master as mast
inner join mail_recievers as det on mast.common_id = det.common_id
group by
       det.status
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I need to get the statuses based on each `common_id`  and need to get each status count for them

Comment: can we get irrespective of status name exist in the column or not still get the count. like `sent` = 10, 'Initiated' = 0, 'bounced ' = 0

Comment: you just need to try it, `group by status` will give you one row for each unique value you have stored in the status column, and the count will relate to that status. If you need more detail, then so do I(we) in the form of `sample data` and the `expected result` - please don't use images for either